# Prestashop install on Wamp error Create database tables

Tags: mysql, wamp, prestashop-1.6

i need Prestashop for my work on my local WAMP server, i had no problems installing wordpress, but prestashop throws error to my face, so i would appreciate any help. 
Installation gets stuck on 12 %.

Create database tables

SQL error on query All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

I tried editing php.ini, changing timeout timer, and i tried changing

```
CREATE TABLE `PREFIX_cart_product` (
  `id_cart` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_address_delivery` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',
  `id_shop` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `id_product_attribute` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cart`,`id_product`,`id_product_attribute`,`id_address_delivery`),
  KEY `id_product_attribute` (`id_product_attribute`),
  KEY `id_cart_order` (`id_cart`, `date_add`, `id_product`, `id_product_attribute`)
) ENGINE=ENGINE_TYPE DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATION;
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE `PREFIX_cart_product` (
  `id_cart` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_address_delivery` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',
  `id_shop` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `id_product_attribute` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE(`id_cart`,`id_product`,`id_product_attribute`,`id_address_delivery`),
  KEY `id_product_attribute` (`id_product_attribute`),
  KEY `id_cart_order` (`id_cart`, `date_add`, `id_product`, `id_product_attribute`)
);​
```

in install/data/db_structures.sql

does nothing, SOS.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution,

replace,

```
`id_product_attribute` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
```

with

```
`id_product_attribute` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
```

in prestashop\install\data\db_structure.sql

VOILA!

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all!

change these 2 lines like this:

```
`id_address_delivery` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NUll DEFAULT '0',
`id_product_attribute` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NOT NULL,
```

**id_address_delivery** and **id_product_attribute** should be `NOT NULL` because they are part of primary key.